# I need to automate the flex section of a web application . Can someone suggest the best way to do that?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, selenium-webdriver

I need to automate the flash(flex) section of a web application. can someone suggest the best way to do that using webdriver

Answer (score 2):

Selenium can not interact with flash elements. If your complete website is build using flash / flex you might want to look into other options than Selenium. If there are just few components then based on the situation, you can try one of the following options with selenium:

- If you have access to the application code / or if you could request developers to expose flash actions then you can use **[Flash Selenium](https://code.google.com/p/flash-selenium/)** OR **[Flex Selenium](https://code.google.com/p/flex-ui-selenium/)**.
- In case there are only a few flash components, e.g. couple of buttons etc. You may look into **[Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org)**
- If there are a lot of components or if the complete website is build in flash, then you should look for commercial tools. e.g. QTP, Telerik TestStudio etc.

Comment: We have a grid which is based on flash and when the displays the combination of data we select and its a major component of product ad i am new to this need a bit more clearification on the topic

Comment: @PuneetSharma I think you should talk to the developers to either expose the api's of the grid or pull the data from the DB / web services etc. I must say that Flex Selenium mentioned above is based on Selenium RC and is a Thin Straw at best but worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

Flex explicitly supports automation, but you have to prepare your application for this. This can be done at compile-time or at load time using a loader SWF and is called instrumenting your application: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=functest_components2_13.html

You can use Selenium with the FlexUISelenium extension to do this (https://code.google.com/p/flex-ui-selenium/). You have to install Selenium and instrument your application using the libs provied by selenium.

There is quite a number of other frameworks available all using the automation way, but there also are graphic test tools, that automate everything purely using image recognition techniques. A few years ago I summed up a comparison of a lot of these: https://dev.c-ware.de/confluence/display/PUBLIC/Functional+Testing+Tools?src=search

If you are able to, I would recommend an automation based approach as Image recognition tools tend to break fast as soon as you simply adjust some colors/fonts/layout.